# Regex for Syntaxdefinition in Sublime (TextMate)

Tags: regex, syntax-highlighting, textmate, sublimetext3

I'm currently writing Regular-Expressions for a Sublime Text - Syntaxdefinition. Sublime has the same format as TextMate, if anyone is familiar with it.

*(If not: you write regular Expressions (Python), and define the scope of the match. And theme-files then define the styling of those scopes)*

**I have troubles with identifying escape-Sequences within strings**

This is the Syntax, which should define strings (in quotes) and escape-Sequences within:

```
- match: ("((?:(\\.)|[^"\\])*)")
  captures:
           '1': {name: punctuation.definition.string.fave}
           '2': {name: string.quotes.fave}
           '3': {name: escape.fave}
```

I want 3 different colors/scopes for the quotes, the string, and all escape-sequences within this String.

This is my output:

[image: output]

As you can see, the regex only matches the last escape-Sequence, and ignores all others.

What is the Problem?

Comment: The problem is that only the last matched pattern is kept as a capture group. I'd use `\G` but it's not implemented in python yet... Otherwise, if you can use the regexp module from pypi, you could perhaps use something like [this](http://regex101.com/r/lD1pV6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a prime example for using the `begin` and `end` syntax with the repository. Try using this

```
patterns:
- begin: \"
  end: \"
  beginCaptures:
    '0': { name: string.quotes.fave }
  endCaptures:
    '0': { name: string.quotes.fave }
  contentName: punctuation.definition.string.fave
  patterns:
  - include: '#escaped_char'
```

With the repository

```
repository:
  escaped_char:
    match: '\\.'
    name: escape.fave
```

Tried to replicate your color theme. With the above, I got this:

[image]

Sorry for reviving a zombie post.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try your solution when I'm working on this issue again, and accept it if it works.